# How to check if two variable in php are same or not?

Tags: php

I want to compare date with database ? so I preg all special character from the date. but some how it always return true  if both vale are not same. What I am doing wrong please help.

```
//input value
$user_dob       = $_POST['user_dob'];
$preg_input_dob  = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "",$user_dob); //output 18101984



//db value 
$date_of_birth = $user_info->date_of_birth;
$preg_db_dob  = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $date_of_birth); //output 18101984


if($preg_input_dob != $preg_db_dob ){
    echo "Date of birth mismatch";
}else{
    echo "Your date of birth is correct";
}
```

Comment: at least put a comment of explanation of negative vote so I can understand that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One explanation here is that the date strings actually have whitespace in them.  Note that your regex replacement actually *spares* whitespace characters.  So, you may try the following:

```
$user_dob = $_POST['user_dob'];
$preg_input_dob  = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $user_dob);
$date_of_birth = $user_info->date_of_birth;
$preg_db_dob = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $date_of_birth);

if ($preg_input_dob != $preg_db_dob) {
    echo "Date of birth mismatch";
}
else {
    echo "Your date of birth is correct";
}
```

By the way, that you are expecting a literal value of `18101984` from your database table might imply that you are storing your dates as text, not as dates.  Ideally, you should be able to directly marshall a MySQL date into a date variable in your PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHP timestamp to compare the date, use strtotime($date) function to convert dates to timestamp it will be in integer format(in form of seconds) then you can easily compare them